# How can I know that editing began on a UITextField that has a UIPickerView as input?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView set as the input of a UITextField. How can I know when the user pressed on the UITextField?

I've tried with the `TouchDown` and `EditingDidStart` events but they won't trigger.

The code where I link the event to a method is the following

```
myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myMethod), for: .<Event>)
```

Comment: What about the various `UITextFieldDelegate` methods?

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, I was looking at the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegate's method `func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` of `UITextFieldDelegate`

and don't forget to become textfield delegate like `yourTextField.delegate = self`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619590-textfielddidbeginediting

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `UITextFieldDelegate` in your project and then delegate it your textfield like :

```
class yourClassName: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yourTextField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

And you need to implement

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //Code here
}
```